# Exceptions in N-tier systems

Tags: java, exception

I have a 4-tier system (db, persistence, business, presentation). The latter 3 tiers all run in one JVM.

I faced some exception handing issues between business and presentation tier. Consider the following code as a *very simplified example*:

```
public void process(String label) throws ValidationException {

    if(label == null) {
        // this is a custom exception that means that one of the arguments invalid
        throw new ValidationException("The label can not be null.");
     }

    if(label.length() != 8) {
        throw new ValidationException("The label has to be 8 letters long."); 
    }

    ... process ...
}
```

The problem here is that the business tire does not know whether an invalid argument is the presentation's or the user's fault.

- Say if the label was provided by the user, then it's the user's fault and the presentation has to show a "validation failed" message with the validation exception's message.
- On the other hand, if the label was generated by the presentation for user, then it's the presentation's fault (probably a bug) and the presentation has to show an "internal error" message.
- Further more, if the label is null, this is 100% the presentation's fault.

The problem arises, when a mixture of user-generated and presentation-generated arguments are passed. In this situation the presentation just can't know what caused the exception. The only thing it got is to show detailed message to the user (because if it's the user's fault, the user got to know the cause). However, it's not acceptable to show the user a detailed error message, while it was the presentation's fault, for it will just confuse the user.

How should I handle exceptions in such situations? Is there any patterns to use?

Comment: Generally that kind of simply validation of user input is considered a presentation-level concern, so if any gets through you can safely consider it a system level error.

Comment: Well it's a simplified example. Very often the validation can't be done by the presentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From OOP philosophy the data knows of about its own behavior.

There are many ways to solve the problem.

Here's one idea:

1. Throw different exceptions for user generated and non-user generated errors. If it is user generated, the presentation layer catches it and shows the message. If it is not, the presentation layer presents a generic message "Internal Error" or "Sorry" or something.
2. The Business layer does not which one is which. So, the data has to know. In your example, `label` cannot be a string. It can be a class.

Wrap all arguments in some class

```
class Label implements Validatable {
    String label;
    @Override
    public void validate() throws BaseValidationException {
         //Check conditions and throw the proper exceptions.
         //Label class should know which validations are user and 
         //Which are presentation and throw appropriate exceptions.
    }
}
```

It will be tedious to create a separate class for all arguments. You can have something like this:

```
class Argument<E>  {
    E realArgument;
    Validator validator;
    public Argument(E value, Validator validator) {
        //implement
    }

}
interface Validator {
    public void validate() throws BaseValidationException;
}
```

Now you can have special validators for things like label ( `LabelValidator implements Validator` ) and have simple validators like `NotNullValidator` for others. These would be associated at time of creation.

At business logic layer, you get

```
void process(Argument<String> label) {
    if (label != null ) label.getValidator().validate();
    //continue.
}
```

At Presentation layer

```
try {
    process(....)
} catch (UserException ex) (
   showMessage(ex.getMessage());
) catch (PresentationError ex) {
  log.fatal(ex.getMessage());
  showMessage("Pre-formatted internal error message");
} catch (Exception ex) { //Unknown exception
  log.fatal(ex.getMessage());
  showMessage("Pre-formatted internal error message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your application generated label code is stabiliazed and meets your specifications it should not be failing the validation checks.
There must be more uses cases that are not covered in the question.

One possible solution I can think of is:

How do you differentiate between a user generated label and application generated label?

In case you do not have any mechanism to differentiate, I would recommend you append some special sequence of chars on a app generated label.

For instance :

- !@_Java
- !@_Python

So this "!@_" would indicate a application generated label and then you can design a solution that handles any validation related issues accordingly.

And in case a label passes the validation step you can always strip the "!@_" part.

Please note that all your label generation happens from only a particular piece of code (Preferably a static utility method).

Comment: What about other data types? Integer? Boolean? Custom object?

Comment: I have only taken into account your sample code. In case of other data types a wrapper class along with Generics would be the way to go.

Comment: Ahh @chips solution should be the way to go, +1 for the example code.